# Is it safe to factory reset my rooted HTC One M8?

Tags: root-access, 6.0-marshmallow, factory-reset, htc-one-m8

I rooted my android marshmallow M8 some time ago and didn't flash any custom ROM. Just used SuperSU and Xposed for some modules and that's basically it. Today the phone was forced shut-down at 13% battery (it had that problem for a while) and when I charged it and tried to turn it on, a message pops out saying that there's an internal problem and it may be unstable until I factory reset the phone. And there is indeed a problem. Messages keep popping out saying that google apps are crashing and I basically can't use it.

So, can I just factory reset it like that? Since it's rooted and everything.

Answer (score 0):

Preform backup just in case. Yes factory reset will return it to factory status. If you have custom recovery then just wipe data and cache's. If you have SuperSu system mode do a full factory wipe.

Comment: So there's no problem with factory resetting it it?

Comment: Nope it will just go back to original status

Comment: @WiseManAnd except for system software. Factory reset won't touch the `/system` partition – so everything that got installed there (e.g. XPosed) should survive it. Despite the name, it doesn't restore it to *factory status* – but just to factory *settings* (i.e. all user data and "normally installed apps" get wiped).

Comment: But user asked if it was safe to restore, I asumed they would flash Xposed recovery through custom recovery when the phone was usable, all suspect apps would need to be uninstalled otherwise and user couldn't do that as phone was unusable.

Answer (score 0):

Yes you can safely factory reset, but as said [here](http://forum.xda-developers.com/general/help/factory-reset-rooted-phone-xposed-t2881118) don't do it from the apps settings, as it won't erase some applications installed in system.
A full factory reset will restore the phone just like it was when out of the factory, not matter what you did (well except radio, and custom ROM and other low level software). So it's safe.